# How to handle local cost map when robot is carrying a shelf in ros2 navigation2?

Tags: navigation, ros2, dwa-local-planner, local-costmap, diff-drive-controller

There is no problem if the robot is not carrying a shelf when using navigation2 with a local cost map with size of (4m x 4m). But when robot is carrying a shelf (see the picture below), if I still use the 4m x 4m local cost map, the robot will see the shelf legs in front of the robot, which will cause issues for the navigation2 stack to work normally. So I am wondering, what's the best way to do under such situation? Can I change the local cost map's size dynamically? Hope someone who is familiar with this can give me some clue, thanks.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are suggesting shrinking the local costmap, that is a bad idea and will have a severe negative effect on DWA Local Planner.

If it were me, I would update the robot's footprint to include the cargo. In ros1, there is a flag to ignore costmap obstacles detected inside the footprint; I don't know if ros2 has implemented this feature.

Comment: This is  a good idea. Another idea would be to use a laser scan mask that reports the legs to any distance far enough away, or close enough, that it doesn't impact navigation. IIRC, there was such a feature somewhere in ROS1.

Comment: So can someone familiar with ros2 confirm if this is possible? thanks

Comment: @billy, thanks for your reply, could you provide more information about how to set up the laser scan mask?

Comment: See section 4.5 on this page: https://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters.
I have a robot where part of the frame blocks the laser. In my case I hardcoded a mask into the laserscanner HW (home built scanner) that modifies the range values only at the angles needed. Short of that I would have used the filters described above...but that is on ROS1. Not sure if this exists in ROS2.

Comment: @billy, thanks, I see the laser_filters also exists in ROS2, but my problem is, I don't want to always filter the laser scan, but only when the robot has carried a shelf, is this possible   to achieve this by laser filter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I guess you can dynamically load configurations for the local cost map based on certain event triggers after you can use the param server for it
also, you might limit the lidar in a way that it doesn't detects the shelf legs as obstacles